# Adding a field to create action in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form for voting for your favourite image:

```
<%= form_for(@imagevote) do |f| %>
  <% @miniature.collections(:photo).each do |collection| %>

    <% if collection.photo.exists? %>

        <%= link_to image_tag(collection.photo.url(:thumb), :retina => true), collection.photo.url(:original), :retina => true, :class => "image-popup-no-margins" %>
        <%= f.radio_button(:collection_id, collection.id) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :voter_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :miniature_id, :value => @miniature.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Vote", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I then want to add the value for collumn `:voted_id` which should be the id of the `collection.user` who received the vote.

I can't work out how to do that in my controller.

What I currently have

```
def create
        @imagevote = Imagevote.new(imagevote_params)
        @collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
        @imagevote.voted_id = @collection.user_id
        if @imagevote.save
            flash[:success] = "Vote registered"
            redirect_to :back
        else
            flash[:success] = "Vote not registered"
            redirect_to :back
        end
    end
```

That gives `Couldn't find Collection without an ID`. The form clearly submits a collection_id and I'm trying to use that to find the collection so that I can then take that collection's `user_id` and pass it to the new model create.

I believe I shouldn't have the `:voted_id` in my `imagevote_params` because it isn't being submitted by a user.

Eek.

**Update:** here is my current log

Started POST "/imagevotes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-20 19:32:20 +0000
Processing by ImagevotesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2FU9X/VJ40UnH70QPy/Iq0Voqo58p5KdcD1B0Q5st0c=", "imagevote"=>{"collection_id"=>"3", "voter_id"=>"4", "miniature_id"=>"10"}, "commit"=>"Vote"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 4 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Collection without an ID):
  app/controllers/imagevotes_controller.rb:17:in `create'

Comment: can you post the params when it gets to the create method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:collection_id` is part of `:imagevote`.

You can access `:collection_id` from your params hash as below:

```
 @collection = Collection.find(params[:imagevote][:collection_id])
```

instead of

```
@collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
```

Comment: Amazing amazing. I didn't realise you could access the param like that. Works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer with an up vote may be :)

Comment: Was just checking that it worked for update too. It does. Outstanding.